# Android Tabs in the middle of the the layout

Tags: android, dialog, android-relativelayout, android-tabhost

I want to have a custom ImageButton above a TabWidget. Below of the Tabs i want to place a TableLayout. Basically my layout should look like this:

```
|---------------------|
|   RelaviteLayout    |
| ------------------- |
| | ImageButton     | |
| ------------------- |
| | TabWidget       | |
| ------------------- |
| | TableLayout     | |
| ------------------- |
|---------------------|
```

The whole layout should be scrollable. And it is placed inside a dialog. The problem is, that this leads to an empty space above the ImageView which does not scroll and has nothing drawn. I guess this is space taken by the TabHost. I have tried setting it to View.INVISIBLE or VIEW.GONE, but this leads to an empty dialog, as everything else exists in the TabHost.

```
-----------------------
|   Empty Space       |
-----------------------
|---------------------|
|   RelaviteLayout    |
| ------------------- |
| | ImageButton     | |
| ------------------- |
| | TabWidget       | |
| ------------------- |
| | TableLayout     | |
| ------------------- |
|---------------------|
```

I have tried the following layout.xml:

```
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:pse="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/myProject
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            <view
                class="project.com.MyImageButton"
                android:id="@+id/myimagebutton"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_yellow_wood"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/btn_element_min_height_mdpi"
                android:minWidth="@dimen/btn_element_min_width_mdpi" />


            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_below="@id/myimagebutton"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/TableView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    <TableRow
                        <TextView
                            android:text="foo"
                            android:layout_column="0"
                            android:padding="3dip" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/TableView02"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    <TableRow
                        <TextView
                            android:text="bar"
                            android:layout_column="0"
                            android:padding="3dip" />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</TabHost>
```

Is there a way to expand the RelativeLayout or the ScrollView to use the whole dialog? Or is there maybe a way to get rid of the TabHost at the top?
Or is the empty space something else? Maybe it is not the TabHost at all. Does anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried it with a normal button, or a static imageView?

Comment: @iaindownie Yes i have tried it. It makes absolutely no difference.